# Unity 2D Overlapping Colliders

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics

I'm developing a 2D point and click adventure and am having issues with the 2D colliders over lapping.

Here is a sample scene of the game:

[image]

What's going on:

- Red Object: the player character. Has a RigidBody2D with kinematic disabled and the main movement code.
- Green Background: is the environment of which the character moves. Uses a Box Collider 2D and has an event trigger for OnGroundClick().
- Purple Object: is the interactable item to be detected. Also has a Box Collider 2D and an event trigger of OnInteractableClick().
- The main camera has a physics 2d ray caster.

This is the code for the player:

```cs
    public NavMeshAgent2D agent;
    public float turnSmoothing = 15f;
    public float speedDampTime = 0.1f;
    public float slowingSpeed = 0.175f;
    public float turnSpeedThreshold = 0.5f;
    public float inputHoldDelay = 0.5f;
    public Rigidbody2D body;
    public bool freezeRotation;
    private WaitForSeconds inputHoldWait;
    private Vector3 destinationPosition;
    private Interactables currentInteractable;
    private bool handleInput = true;

    private const float navMeshSampleDistance = 4f;
    private const float stopDistanceProportion = 0.1f;

    public void OnGroundClick(BaseEventData data)
    {
        Debug.Log("OnGroundClick");
        if (!handleInput)
        {
            return;
        }
        currentInteractable = null;
        PointerEventData pData = (PointerEventData)data;
        NavMeshHit2D hit;
        if (NavMesh2D.SamplePosition(pData.pointerCurrentRaycast.worldPosition,
            out hit, navMeshSampleDistance, NavMesh2D.AllAreas))
        {
            destinationPosition = hit.position;
        }
        else 
        {
            destinationPosition = pData.pointerCurrentRaycast.worldPosition;
        }
        agent.SetDestination(destinationPosition);
        agent.isStopped = false; //agent.Resume();
    }

    public void OnInteractableClick(Interactables interactable)
    {
        Debug.Log("OnInteractableClick");
        if (!handleInput)
        {
            return;
        }
        currentInteractable = interactable;
        destinationPosition = currentInteractable.interactionLocation.position;
        agent.SetDestination(destinationPosition);
        agent.isStopped = false;
    }
```

Note: NavMesh2D is a third party asset for creating nav meshes for 2D environments

I have tried changed the z position on each collider to no effect.

How can I detect both colliders individually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added some details to the raycaster for the background. Moving it to the far back of the z axis, I then modified it's code.

```
public void OnGroundClick(BaseEventData data)
{
    Debug.Log("OnGroundClick");
    if (!handleInput)
    {
        return;
    }
    currentInteractable = null;
    PointerEventData pData = (PointerEventData)data;
    Vector3 worldPoint = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(pData.pointerCurrentRaycast.worldPosition);
    worldPoint.z = Camera.main.transform.position.z;
    Ray ray = new Ray(worldPoint, new Vector3(0, 0, 1));
    RaycastHit2D hitInfo = Physics2D.GetRayIntersection(ray);
    NavMeshHit2D hit;
    if (NavMesh2D.SamplePosition(pData.pointerCurrentRaycast.worldPosition,
        out hit, navMeshSampleDistance, NavMesh2D.AllAreas))
    {
        destinationPosition = hit.position;
    }
    else 
    {
        destinationPosition = pData.pointerCurrentRaycast.worldPosition;
    }
    agent.SetDestination(destinationPosition);
    agent.isStopped = false; //agent.Resume();
}
```